# Problem executing Hilbert transform on $x$-$y$ plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, hilbert-transform

I have a wav signal I have imported into MATLAB, and I would like to find its envelope. I want to do this via the Hibert transform. But whenever I try to find the Hilbert transform of the signal I receive the following error message:

```
>Warning:HILBERT ignores imaginary part of input. 
>> In hilbert (line 38) 
Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type
'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line'.

>>Error in hilbert (line 39)
  xr = real(xr);
```

Here are screenshots of the corresponding code:

[image]

I have found the function `real.mat` and made sure it is in a filepath accessible to MATLAB using the `pathtool` command. I still encounter this problem.

What should I do?

-Joseph

Comment: Your input signal is probably not what it should be. Check what it is, it should be  a vector of doubles.

Comment: You are calling with the wrong arguments. Looks like you are passing it a line object (which something like plot() would return) and not with the actual data.

Comment: Votes and best answer validation are required for this question

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a command like `data = plot(x,y)` and then trying to compute `hilbert(data)`. This looks consistent with your title `executing Hilbert transform on xx-yy plot`. Instead, you should try `plot(x,abs(hilbert(y)))`.